# How to draw circle on UIImageView without adding layer in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, draw

I want to draw a circle on `UIImageView`. I have tried it but it didn't work.

This is a example image of what i want to achieve:

[image]

The circle should be drawn on where user taps on `UIImageView` and I want to do it without adding any `sublayer`.

Is it some way to do this?
so far i have used this code from the internet but it didn't worked.

```
 - (UIImage *)imageByDrawingCircleOnImage:(UIImage *)image
                                  pointX:(float) x
                                 PointY:(float) y
{
    // begin a graphics context of sufficient size
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);

    // draw original image into the context
    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

    // get the context for CoreGraphics
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // set stroking color and draw circle
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];

    // make circle rect 5 px from border
    CGRect circleRect = CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                   image.size.width,
                                   image.size.height);
    circleRect = CGRectInset(circleRect, x, y);

    // draw circle
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(ctx, circleRect);

    // make image out of bitmap context
    UIImage *retImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // free the context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return retImage;
}
```

Comment: Could you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: Somehow I don't think you are building for iOS 4. Please tag properly.

Comment: give corner radius to half of the width

Comment: see my answer sohail, hope it helps you :)

Comment: i have attached the code and screen shot of the image help needed Isouza rmaddy

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your object's view is square, Set the `cornerRadius` to half of the width or height.
`maskToBounds` set your image as per shape of rounded `imageView`

For example,add this code for your requirement,

```
yourImageView.layer.cornerRadius = yourImageView.imageView.frame.size.height /2;
yourImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: the image is loaded in the image view i want to draw circle over the image of small radius .

Comment: Read this, it help you bro:  https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/09/04/how-to-draw-circles-where-ever-someone-taps-your-screen-iphone-ipad-ios/